# Calling SOAP service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, web-services, soap

I'm using the following code to call SOAP service:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularSoap'])

.factory("testService", ['$soap',function($soap) {
var base_url = "http://localhost/B1-MailManagement/MailManagementService.svc";

return {
    GetData: function(cnNumber){

        return $soap.post(base_url,"/", {cnNumber: "234423432423"});
    }
}
}])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, testService) {

$scope.track = function(){

    testService.GetData("898779879").then(function(response) {
        $scope.response = response;
    });        
}
})
```

I followed this link to do this: [SOAP Web Services in Angular and Ionic](http://mcgivery.com/soap-web-services-angular-ionic/)

But, it's not working. Instead, it gives this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/B1-MailManagement/MailManagementService.svc. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400
```

I also added CORS extension in Chrome for this, but nothing seems to be working.

What's the right way to call a SOAP service using AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, its not wise to try to call SOAP service from Javascript. So, I used restful service instead and added following code in my Global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if( HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

and it worked.